# Decrypt mail to Exchange public folder

Tags: vba, powershell, email, outlook

I have received some encrypted mails. I want to store them in an Exchange public folder. The mails shall be stored decrypted so that others can read them without the need for my private key certificate.

Using the Outlook GUI it's possible to do so using the Forward action with encryption disabled. This has the drawback that the sender of the mail is replaced with my address. Not so good, but at least the mail encryption is removed.

My Outlook is configured to use two accounts. The default account is an external POP3 account. But the mail shall be forwarded directly to the Exchange server. Therefore I want to overwrite the `SendUsingAccount` property of the mail. But this causes an error with the Exchange server.

```
$Exchange="name-of-the-server"
$PublicFolderAddress="address-of-the-folder"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject OUTLOOK.APPLICATION
$Account = $Outlook.Session.Accounts | Where-Object { $_.ExchangeMailboxServerName -eq $Exchange }
$Namespace = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$Mailbox = $Namespace.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "my-mail-address" }
$Inbox = $Mailbox.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Inbox" }
$Mail = $Inbox.Items[1]
# create forwarded mail
$Forward = $Mail.Forward()
$Forward.Recipients.Add($PublicFolderAddress)
$Forward.SendUsingAccount = $Account
$FW.Send()
```

But the assignment `$Forward.SendUsingAccount = $Account` fails with exception.

> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)

- How can I define the SMTP server for the mail to avoid sending to the POP3 server?
- How can I keep the original sender name and address so that the mail is effectively "moved" to the public folder? The encryption shall be removed in this process.

**Edit:** The main objective is to decrypt the message an make it public on the Exchange server.

Comment: Your suggested method appears to allow sensitive material to be intercepted. Removing encryption to share mail is universally needed. Your Outlook ribbon could have a tab for Security/Encryption where you can Unsecure or Unencrypt. This is different from the decryption to open the mail. Once you have unsecured you can move the mail to a shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just forward it and keep the signature intact. You can move the message to any folder using `MailItem.Move()`.

Comment: In the first paragraph I wrote why I need the script. The script code doesn't show how encrypted messages are handled. But if I use the (GUI) move or copy operation the mail keeps encrypted. How would a `MailItem.Move` store the message without encryption?

Comment: I think you are missingh my point - what you want is to send a message pretending to be the sender of the original mesage. Exchange won't let you spoof a sender.What yo uneed is to directly create a message in teh target folder. A bit compicated using OOM, but easly doable in Extended MAPI or Redemption.

Comment: Nope. I could accept to lose the sender. Once again: `I have received some encrypted mails ... The mails shall be stored not encrypted `. That's the important point. If the `move` stores the message decrypted, it would be great because sender, date, etc. will be unchanged. Using `Send` I get a new mail containing the text readable for everyone how has access to the Exchange server. But that's the second point I would like to achieve. -- I already stressed in the text that decryption is the topic.

Comment: I don't think you can do that using OOM. If using Redemption is an option, you can create an instance of the RDOSession object, set its RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT property to Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT, reopen the item using RDOSession.GetMesageFromID (it will return RDOEncryptedItem object for an encrypted message) , reopen the PF folder using RDOSession.GetFolderFromID, then call RDOEncryptedItem.CopyTo() passing the target folder.